# Как не загружать модули с requirements при каждом старте контейнера docker?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

Всем привет,

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 testDj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8888:8000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3


WORKDIR /opt/web/app
COPY . /opt/web/app


RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Как закэшировать загруженные модули?

При старте докера выполняется загрузка модулей пайтоне, а это долго.

Запускаю докер с pycharm docker-compose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Необходимо сначала скопировать requirements.txt, и поставить пакеты, а потом копировать весь проект. Т.к. докер собирает слоями, то он начнет с того места, где произошли изменения, и не будет ставить пакеты заново.
Dockerfile должен будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
FROM python:3

COPY requirements.txt /opt/web/app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /opt/web/app
COPY . /opt/web/app
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что выполняя `COPY . /opt/web/app` вы копируете папку проекта в докер, следовательно при каждом запуске контейнера он будет билдеться т.к. файлы проекта меняются. Следует папку проекта монтировать в уже готовый контейнер

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов а можно примерчик

Comment: @MelisZhoroev requirements.txt я полагаю у вас тоже меняется в ходе работы над проектом?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов но не часто как сам код

Comment: @MelisZhoroev но все же меняется. Сейчас напишу развернутый ответ, как я бы оформил docker контейнер

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов Жду.......

Comment: @hoholok предложил лучшее решение, но `COPY requirements.txt /` я бы делал вне `WORKDIR` . Если запустили без `--build`, то изменения `requirements.txt` не повлияют.

Answer (score 4):

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: python:3
    container_name: python_web
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/web/app
    working_dir: /opt/web/app
    command: python3 testDj/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8888:8000"
```

В этом случаи Dockerfile вовсе не нужен.

**Makefile**

```
# Start docker container
start-container:
    docker-compose up -d

# Stop docker container
stop-container:
    docker-compose stop

# Dependencies
dep-install:
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Dependencies install into container
dep-install-into-container
    docker-compose exec web bash -c "make dep-install"
```

В любой момент можно поставить зависимости не останавливая контейнер, правда я не знаю, как это будет взаимодействовать с уже запущенном приложении. С питоном никогда не работал.

Я бы так сделал

Comment: "В этом случаи Dockerfile вовсе не нужен." - я тоже думал так, но делается же работы написанные в Dockerfile это копирование, скачивание модулей или вы именно про ваш пример что тут не нужен Dockerfile?

Comment: Именно про мой пример. Я не говорю, что он вам 100% может подойди, это все лишь мое представление решение данной задачи. В Вашем `Dockerfile` копирование проекта и загрузка зависимостей. Не думаю, что все это должно быть в контейнере.

Comment: хорошо я понял, смотри почему я не могу вызвать кодманы в контейнере docker-compose exec python_web -c "pip3 install requarments.txt" - выводит No such service: python_web

Comment: Ооуу ошибся немного `docker-compose exec web bash -c "pip3 install requarments.txt"`
В этом случаи в `docker-compose.yml` особо не нужна секция `container_name`